# Autostart process and respawn only if error

Tags: debian, boot, process-management

I am trying to start a process_A automatically (on startup) just after another process_B ends (which makes some updates in the system and needs the process_A to be off) and then if process_A crash or finish by error, restart.

I was trying with a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Launch updater on start
process_B

# Launch process_A
until process_A
do
    # Restart in case of error/crash
    echo "process_A stopped with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2;
    sleep 2;
done

# Shutdown system
shutdown -hP now
```

And the problem I have is how to launch this script correctly on start because if I use an autostart like

```
$HOME/.conf/autostart/script_launcher.desktop
```

then process_A fails because there are some needed services that are not up yet I guess. If I launch this script manually, it runs with no errors.

I was thinking on init.d service to start process_A on startup and respawn it automatically but i need to execute process_B before and only on startup.

I'm using Debian Wheezy.

Comment: that bin/bash line doesn't look right; is that pseudocode or the actual script?

Comment: is the script, most of it, but yes, i wrote it wrong, edited.

Comment: What does 'on startup' imply? At cold boot or when login as a user to a GUI desktop? Does it work if you put a 'sleep 180' in the beginning? If so, dump a list of processes running before and after sleep.

Comment: yeah, a sleep works because It gives time to postgresql, but then I tried with: "if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep postgresql | wc -l) = 0 )) then /etc/init.d/postgresql start fi" but I also need a sleep after this

Comment: I have purged SLiM and prepared an alternative to autologin and startx and everything works well after that, no problems with any services